# Javascript make image in data-attr an inline background image after X seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays

## **The problem**

I have a `div` that has a list of image paths stored in a data attribute, like so:

```
<!-- Multiple background images stored in data-attr -->
<div class="banner" data-bg="http://placehold.it/350x150, http://placehold.it/350x250, http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
```

I have written some Javascript that retrieves the data attribute and splits the URLs into an array:

```
function backgroundPhader(){
    //get bg el
    var bg_el = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0];
  
  //make empty bg array
  var bg_arr = [];
  
  //console.log(bg_el);
  //get data-attr of bgs
  var bg_data = bg_el.getAttribute("data-bg");
  
  //console.log(bg_data);
  bg_arr = bg_data.split(",");
  
  console.log(bg_arr);
}

backgroundPhader();
```

### Where to next

What I now want to try do if it's not too complex with pure Javascript is to take each item in the array and apply it as an inline background-image - one at a time over a set period of time. I can't work out how to pull out a single item from the array and apply it as an inline style.

Help pointing me in the right direction would be great. I also have a [fiddle if it helps](https://jsfiddle.net/mjyz1syu/7/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `setInterval` will invoke the function after specified interval.

`split` will split string and return array using mentioned `separator`. One can use `index` of array to get the values of the array.

Try this:

```js
function backgroundPhader() {
  var bg_el = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0];
  var bg_data = bg_el.getAttribute("data-bg");
  var bg_arr = bg_data.split(",");
  var val = 0;
  var iterator = function() {
    if (val > bg_arr.length - 1) {
      val = 0;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg_arr[val] + ')';
    ++val;
  };
  iterator();
  setInterval(iterator, 1000);
}

backgroundPhader();
```

```html
<!-- Multiple background images stored in data-attr -->
<div class="banner" data-bg="http://placehold.it/350x150, http://placehold.it/350x250, http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
```

Comment: aha! that's brilliant. What would be a good method to handle first page load before the first image is set after the seconds defined to avoid just having a blank div?